# subclass is Serializable superclass is not serializable

Tags: java, serialization

I just started with this topic. My understanding says that , if you want to save instance variables of a class , so  that it can be used later... you may use "serializable" interface with no methods defined...
But i have a doubt that , what happens in inheritance... Suppose my superclass is not-serialized wheras sub-class is serialized...can i save my superclass instance variables ?? 
Although, i know this... the costructor of superclass is being called and it will run...but what dat mean? is it mean that , i can't save instance variable of superclass....

In the below program... the created file will store numerical values(43,23) or just variables "height" and "weight"???

```
import java.io.*;

class A  {

String sex;

public void gone(String sex){

this.sex = sex;

System.out.println("i m " + sex); 

}

}


public class serialio1 extends A implements Serializable  {

int height;

int weight;

public static void main(String[] args){

serialio1 myBox = new serialio1();

myBox.go(43,23);

try{

FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("foo.ser");

ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);

os.writeObject(myBox);

os.close();

FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("foo.ser");

ObjectInputStream ms = new ObjectInputStream(fileStream);

Object one = ms.readObject();

Object two = ms.readObject();

int h = (int) one;

int  w = (int) two;

ms.close();

System.out.println("saved values" + h + w);

} catch(Exception ex){

ex.printStackTrace();

}

}

public void go(int height , int weight) {

this.height = height;

this.weight = weight;

System.out.println(" height is " + height);

System.out.println(" weight is " + weight);

}

}
```

Comment: The [tag:javascript] tag has been removed. I don't see how your question has anything to do with JavaScript. Are you confusing it with Java perhaps? Also, please consider formatting your posted code. All left-justified code is hard to read and understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java object Serialization and inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632148/java-object-serialization-and-inheritance)

Comment: and moreover i am getting exception....i don't kno y??

Comment: And moreover if you're getting an exception you should include it in your question, along with the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to super class fields from the subclass you can implement custom serialization

```
class X {
    int x;
}

class Y extends X implements java.io.Serializable {

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        out.writeInt(x);
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        x = in.readInt();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose my superclass is not-serialized wheras sub-class is serialized...can i save my superclass instance variables?

Yes, but you have to write extra code, as show in Evgeny's answer.

> Although, i know this... the costructor of superclass is being called and it will run...but what dat mean? is it mean that , i can't save instance variable of superclass....

I really can't make any sense out of this, but if you're just repeating your earlier question, the answer is the same too.

> In the below program... the created file will store numerical values(43,23) or just variables "height" and "weight"???

I can't make any sense of of that either. It is a non-question. It will store the *object* that you pass to `writeObject(),` and that is what you will get back from `readObject().` In your case, a `serialio1` object, not integers.