# GWT result state changes after dispatch

Tags: gwt, gwtp

data item boolean flag won't hold its state when item is returned from server through dispatcher to Presenter (client side).

**shared package**

```
 public class ResourceItem extends BaseResourceItem implements IsSerializable {

  private String name;

  public ResourceItem() {
    super();
  }

  public ResourceItem(String name) {
    super(true);
    this.name = name;
  } 
}

public class BaseResourceItem {

  private boolean removeEnabled = true;

  public BaseResourceItem() {
    super();
  }

  public BaseResourceItem(boolean removeEnabled) {
    super();
    this.removeEnabled = removeEnabled;
  }

  public boolean isRemoveEnabled() {
    return removeEnabled;
  }

  public void setRemoveEnabled(boolean removeEnabled) {
    this.removeEnabled = removeEnabled;
  }
}
```

Flag in question is removeEnabled . By default it's true, and even though I set it to false in server side, when Presenter gets it, it's been set to false for some reason. Am I missing something with serialization? (can't think of anything else at this point).

**Server package**

```
@GenDispatch
public class GetModelSettings {

    @Out(1)
    List<ResourceItem> listOfSettings;
}

public class GetModelSettingsHandler implements ActionHandler<GetModelSettingsAction, GetModelSettingsResult> {

        @Override
        public GetModelSettingsResult execute(GetModelSettingsAction action, ExecutionContext context)
                throws ActionException {

            ResourceItem item1 = new ResourceItem();
            ResourceItem item2 = new ResourceItem();
            item2.setRemoveEnabled(false);

            list.add(item1);
            list.add(item2);

            // item1 -> true
            // item2 -> false

            return new GetModelSettingsResult(list);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, a simple handler return a list. At this point, data is correct, one item has flag set to true, the other one to false.

**Client package**

```
public class ModelSettingsPresenter {

    dispatcher.execute(new GetModelSettingsAction(), new AsyncCallback<GetModelSettingsResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(GetModelSettingsResult result) {
            itemList = result.getListOfSettings(); 
            // itemList.get(0) -> true
            // itemList.get(1) -> true
        }
    });
}
```

Data items both have flags set to true in this presenter. Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with serialization used with inheritance.

> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is serializable. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored from the stream.
>
> More on it can be found in different thread [Java object Serialization and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632148/java-object-serialization-and-inheritance)